# awk - apply to all fields except one?

Tags: bash, awk, field

Have a file where I want to preform awk Gsub on all fields except the first field.  There are variable number of fields, so i am trying to figure out if I can write a conditional command to apply to all but $1.

I'd even work if there were a way to say ${2-20}.  However, I can't seem to find this type of a command anywhere for awk.  Thanks.  Here's an example to practice on.

I am looking to do something like this:

EDIT

I tried this but it did not change anything.

```
awk 'x!=$1{gsub("C","g",x);gsub("G","c",x);gsub("T","a",x);gsub("A","t",x)}{print}' F1 

F1
G 6472 193 0.0 0.0 193.0 0.0 0.0   C   d
T 6482 91 91.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 T     d
G 7482 187 0.0 0.0 187.0 0.0 0.0   C   d
T 8860 74 0.0 0.0 0.0 74.0 0.0    A  d
G 9254 52 0.0 0.0 52.0 0.0 0.0   C   d
A 10059 78 78.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 T     d
G 10476 757 0.0 1.0 755.0 1.0 0.0   C   d
G 16122 125 0.0 1.0 124.0 0.0 0.0   C   d
G 17053 316 0.0 0.0 316.0 0.0 0.0   C   d
G 19312 56 0.0 0.0 55.0 1.0 0.0   C   d


Desired out
G 6472 193 0.0 0.0 193.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
T 6482 91 91.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 a     d
G 7482 187 0.0 0.0 187.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
T 8860 74 0.0 0.0 0.0 74.0 0.0    t  d
G 9254 52 0.0 0.0 52.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
A 10059 78 78.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 a     d
G 10476 757 0.0 1.0 755.0 1.0 0.0   g   d
G 16122 125 0.0 1.0 124.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
G 17053 316 0.0 0.0 316.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
G 19312 56 0.0 0.0 55.0 1.0 0.0   g   d
```

Thanks.

Comment: looks like only $(NF-1) is changed in your desired output.  Is that correct? Always good to include the code you're currently using. AND ... Don't forget about `for (i=2;i<NF;i++) { sub(/x/, "y", $i); }`. Good luck.

Comment: This has worked.  You should put it as an answer so I can vote for it.  One thing that would make it better (And another issue I run into with awk) is there a way I can maintain the blank spaces after $8?  Awk just see's white space and will not define " " as a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, ... going off your code:

```
awk '{ s=$1; sub($1,""); gsub("C","g"); gsub("G","c"); gsub("T","a"); gsub("A","t"); print s $0 }' filename
```

To preserve the whitespaces I used `sub($1,"")` instead of `$1=""`.

Comment: very simple and it worked.  I am trying to figure out how using sub($1,"") preserved the white space...  can you explain that (like why it didn't just make $1="".

Comment: Because awk recomputes the whole record when re-assigning fields,( `$1="something", $2="...",` etc ), removing any extra whitespace in the process. Whereas in case of the substitution of the whole record `sub($1,"")`, ( equal to `sub($1,"",$0)` ), there's no field re-assigning taking place, so the whitespaces are preserved.

Answer (score 2):

this line does what you want:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{d["C"]="g";d["G"]=c;d["T"]="a";d["A"]="t"}
      $(NF-1) in d{$(NF-1)=d[$(NF-1)]}7' file
```

Comment: This worked nicely.  I also like that it allows me to replace a capital with another capital and not have to worry about it being written over by the subsequent rule like I do with gsub script.  ie I can do d["G"]="C".  Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option for translating characters, maybe overkill for this particular example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function tr(old,new,str,        oldA,newA,i) {
    split(old,oldA,"")
    split(new,newA,"")
    for (i=1;i in oldA;i++) {
        gsub(oldA[i],newA[i],str)
    }
    return str
}

{ print $1 tr("CGTA","gcat",substr($0,2)) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
G 6472 193 0.0 0.0 193.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
T 6482 91 91.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 a     d
G 7482 187 0.0 0.0 187.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
T 8860 74 0.0 0.0 0.0 74.0 0.0    t  d
G 9254 52 0.0 0.0 52.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
A 10059 78 78.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 a     d
G 10476 757 0.0 1.0 755.0 1.0 0.0   g   d
G 16122 125 0.0 1.0 124.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
G 17053 316 0.0 0.0 316.0 0.0 0.0   g   d
G 19312 56 0.0 0.0 55.0 1.0 0.0   g   d
```

Answer (score 0):

combining Kents answer and shellters answer in the comments, I came up with this script which allows me to change capitols to capitols and maintain the white spice as it originally was.

```
awk '
        BEGIN{d["G"]="C";d["C"]="G";d["T"]="A";d["A"]="T";FS="";OFS=""}
        {for(i=2;i<(NF+1);i++)
                {if($i in d)
                        $i=d[$i]}
                                }
        {print}' $1

Output:
G 6472 193 0.0 0.0 193.0 0.0 0.0   G   d
T 6482 91 91.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 A     d
G 7482 187 0.0 0.0 187.0 0.0 0.0   G   d
T 8860 74 0.0 0.0 0.0 74.0 0.0    T  d
G 9254 52 0.0 0.0 52.0 0.0 0.0   G   d
A 10059 78 78.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 A     d
G 10476 757 0.0 1.0 755.0 1.0 0.0   G   d
G 16122 125 0.0 1.0 124.0 0.0 0.0   G   d
G 17053 316 0.0 0.0 316.0 0.0 0.0   G   d
G 19312 56 0.0 0.0 55.0 1.0 0.0   G   d
```